# Two-factor bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Working from the following dataframe:

```
    > foo
        species density day percent  
    1  species1    high   1    0.40  
    2  species1     low   1    0.20  
    3  species1  medium   1    0.40  
    4  species2    high   1    0.35  
    5  species2     low   1    0.10  
    6  species2  medium   1    0.55  
    7  species3    high   1    0.35  
    8  species3     low   1    0.20  
    9  species3  medium   1    0.45  
    10 species4    high   1    0.30  
    11 species4     low   1    0.20  
    12 species4  medium   1    0.50  
    13 species1    high 100    0.50  
    14 species1     low 100    0.40  
    15 species1  medium 100    0.10  
    16 species2    high 100    0.40  
    17 species2     low 100    0.05  
    18 species2  medium 100    0.55  
    19 species3    high 100    0.65  
    20 species3     low 100    0.05  
    21 species3  medium 100    0.30  
    22 species4    high 100    0.40  
    23 species4     low 100    0.20  
    24 species4  medium 100    0.40
```

I have created the following faceted bar graph:

```
require(ggplot2)

foo$density<-factor(foo$density,levels=c('low','medium','high'))

d <- ggplot(foo, aes(x=species, y=percent, fill=density)) +
    geom_bar(aes(width=.65), stat="identity") +
    facet_grid(. ~ day)
```

[image]

However, I would like to merge these graphs to create a single two-factor bar graph. On the x-axis, each day- 1 and 100 - would be grouped by species. Any suggestions on how to create this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one

```
foo$species_day <- with(data = foo, expr = paste(species, day))
d <-ggplot(foo, aes(x=species_day, y=percent, fill=density)) +
      geom_bar(aes(width=.65), stat="identity")
```

[image]
You can rearrange the levels if you want.

Comment: @joran I like the idea of faceting by species, but then the labeling of the x-axis becomes an issue.  I would like 'species' to be the focal x-axis label (on the bottom of the graph) and 'day' to be set w/in each 'species' (also on the bottom).

Comment: @MYaseen208 Thanks for this suggestion- I like how it is all on a single graph.  Is there anyway to create more and less space between bars to 'group' by species?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that incorporates @Joran's suggestion along with your requirements.

I have changed `day` to a factor, but also changed the default x-axis label to "Species". Also, because `density` is clearly a sequential factor, I have use a sequential color scale from Color Brewer (http://colorbrewer2.org/). You can experiment with color scales by changing  `palette` number or calling palette by name `scale_fill_brewer(palette="GnBu")`. Find the palette names on the Color Brewer web page.

```
foo <- read.table(header=TRUE,
                 text="species  density day percent  
                    1  species1    high   1    0.40  
                    2  species1     low   1    0.20  
                    3  species1  medium   1    0.40  
                    4  species2    high   1    0.35  
                    5  species2     low   1    0.10  
                    6  species2  medium   1    0.55  
                    7  species3    high   1    0.35  
                    8  species3     low   1    0.20  
                    9  species3  medium   1    0.45  
                    10 species4    high   1    0.30  
                    11 species4     low   1    0.20  
                    12 species4  medium   1    0.50  
                    13 species1    high 100    0.50  
                    14 species1     low 100    0.40  
                    15 species1  medium 100    0.10  
                    16 species2    high 100    0.40  
                    17 species2     low 100    0.05  
                    18 species2  medium 100    0.55  
                    19 species3    high 100    0.65  
                    20 species3     low 100    0.05  
                    21 species3  medium 100    0.30  
                    22 species4    high 100    0.40  
                    23 species4     low 100    0.20  
                    24 species4  medium 100    0.40")

foo$density <- factor(foo$density, levels=c("low", "medium", "high"))
foo$day <- factor(paste("Day", foo$day, sep="_"))

library(ggplot2)

d2 <- ggplot(foo, aes(x=day, y=percent, fill=density)) +
      theme_bw() +
      geom_bar(width=0.95, stat="identity") +
      scale_fill_brewer(type="seq", palette=15) +
      xlab("Species") +
      opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(size=6)) +
      facet_grid(. ~ species)

ggsave("barplot_1.png", d2, width=6, height=4)
```

[image]

One problem I have not solved is that the levels of `density` do not stack in the proper order (for me or in @MYaseen208's answer). Stacking is correct in the original post. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: good suggestions.  I was hoping to have the `species` names on the bottom of the  graph too (in between `day` and the x-axis label).  I would like `day` to share a single x-axis and there not to be lines demarcating each species (so it appears to be a single graph).  I will be using Color Brewer and other fancy tricks for the final product, but for simplicities sake I omitted those details.  As for the stacking issue- not sure what it could be, but if you save the data as a .csv and import it that way it stacks correctly.

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help (a little, I hope.) I'm not sure what it would mean for "`day` to share a single x-axis". As for placing species labels along the x-axis -- it may be most expedient to bring a pdf version into Adobe Illustrator (or Inkscape) to complete the customization. (I'm sure there are hacks to do what you want with ggplot2 or grid code, but there's a point of diminishing returns).